# is it possible to insert json into cassandra without creating table

Tags: cassandra, nosql

How can I insert json objects to Cassandra table without creating table? Can Cassandra parse json to table which is not created? Or, Can I create a table with no column and insert json?

Thanks.

Comment: Ceate table then INSERT INTO users JSON '{"id": "user123", "age": 42, "state": "TX"}';

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After Cassandra 2.2 you can [insert json directly](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/whats-new-in-cassandra-2-2-json-support), but the table still should be created beforehead.

Answer (score 4):

**You need to create table First, then you can insert data**

You can create table like the below one :

```
CREATE TABLE json_data (
    id timeuuid PRIMARY KEY,
    data text
);
```

And you can insert the json as string with the below query :

```
INSERT INTO json_data (id , data ) VALUES ( now(), '{"first_name" : "Ashraful",  "last_name" : "Islam"}') ;
```